# Omitting void return type not working as void* argument

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, void-pointers, std-pair

I am trying to pass a uintptr_t and a void* to a lambda using std::pair.

This is how my function looks like that accepts the uintptr_t and void* as pair:

```
void call( std::pair<std::uintptr_t, void*> addresses )
{
  const auto [p1, p2] = addresses;
  //do stuff here
}
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
    call(
        { reinterpret_cast< std::uintptr_t >( start ),
            [ ] ( void* main_app ) -> void*
            {
                //do stuff here, then return res for func

                return res;
            }
        }
    );
```

The error I am getting is:

`C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are: (uintptr_t, lambda [](void *main_app)->void *)`

I am using C++20 (Latest Draft)

Thanks for taking your time to read this. And hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can see what I am doing wrong.

Regards.

Comment: Do you want to pass the value that the lambda returns to `call`? If so, you need to invoke the lambda with `()` after the lambda body.

Comment: The same problem with a regular function: `void* fun(void* main_app) { ... return res; } /*...*/ call({reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(start), fun});`

Comment: @cigien, If I do that then I get another error saying:

C++ function cannot be called with the given argument list            object type is: lambda [](void *main_application)->void *

Comment: lambdas aren't (necessarily) pointers and are not guaranteed to be castable to `void*`

Comment: Yes, your lambda expects a `void*` so you have to provide an appropriate argument inside the `()`. What I was pointing out is that you need to invoke/call the lambda somehow.

Comment: @infamoushvher Seems both error messages are telling you what is wrong. You are trying to pass the result of calling the lambda to your `call` function, so you need to actually call the lambda. And since your lambda expects a `void*` argument you need to provide one when you make the call. I sense there's some context here which you aren't providing. Perhaps you should ditch the lambda and provide a named function instead. It would make the code easier to understand and since the lambda is not capturing anything, it's not needed.

Comment: What are you really supposed to be doing? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Do you need to call the lambda, and use its return value as the second element in the pair? Or do you want to pass a pointer to the function itself in the pair, so that `call` call call it later? Why then are you using `void*`? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::make_pair` to create a `std::pair` object and pass it to your call function.

```
call(
    std::make_pair(
        reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(start),
        [](void* main_app) -> void*
        {
            // do stuff here, then return res for func
            return res;
        }
    )
);
```